# SVN integration for Flash Builder 4 NOT Subclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, svn, flash-builder

I'm looking for a good SVN plugin for Adobe Flash Builder 4 that is NOT subclipse, since I am currently working with subclipse on my setup and it is quite terrible in every way.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a recommendation engine, so I voted to close.  That said, I use SmartSVN which is a stand alone SVN Client.  I tried a lot of clients (Both standalone and integrated into IDEs) before landing on SmartSVN; and am consistently happy with it.

Comment: The only (major) alternative for Eclipse/FlashBuilder is [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/). Not sure if it's any better though...

Answer (score 0):

I think subclipse is good, if you donot like it, Maybe you can find more plugin here:

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/taxonomy/term/15/favorites